# Como não sobrepor componentes usando TailwindCSS?

Tags: css, vue.js, componentes

Eu criei um componente `Header` e quando eu registro ele em um componente chamado `Home`, o Header sobrepõe o `h3` e mesmo eu tentando colocar um display block em cada componente, não funcionou

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <Header />
    <div class="flex m-5">
      <h3>Hello</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    Header: () => import('@/components/Header.vue')
  }
}
</script>
```

Header:

```
    <template>
          <nav
        class="flex fixed w-full items-center justify-between px-6 h-16 bg-white text-gray-700 border-b border-gray-200 z-10"
      >
            <!-- Etc... -->
        </nav>
</template>
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar e tirar essa duvida, eu tenho que usar um display block mesmo?

Comment: Por acaso vc colocou position absolute ou fixed em algum elemento dentro do container?

Comment: Olá, não, coloquei não!

Comment: @TMoraes o @huocsl está certo, veja, tem um `fixed` no seu `<nav>` ele faz com que a posição dessa tag vá lá pra cima e ele vai sobrepor tudo que não tiver `position` definido.
 Removendo a classe fixed deve resolver o problema, ou... tu pode adicionar um `mb-16` pra jogar tudo pra baixo do seu `<nav>` (isso acho que seria melhor como resposta a escrita vai ficar estranha aqui xD)

Comment: Oxiii, verdade, comi mosca kkk mas de qlqr forma eu setei block no meu header. Obrigado @Pliavi